# cmake boost trouble and intern can't install dlib

Tags: cmake, python-3.5, boost-python, dlib

Somehow when installed python3.5 with boost, cmake can't find it.
I'm trying to install lib and when I do I get this error. I have boost - python installed.

```
CMake Warning at 
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.6.0_1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1459 (message):
  No header defined for python-py34; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/pascaljardin/Desktop/dlib-19.0/dlib/add_python_module:60 (FIND_PACKAGE)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)
-- Could NOT find Boost
-- Could NOT find Boost
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/libpython3.5.dylib (found suitable version "3.5.2", minimum required is "3.4")

--  *****************************************************************************************************
--  To compile Boost.Python yourself download boost from boost.org and then go into the boost root folder
--  and run these commands:
--     ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=python
--     ./b2
--     sudo ./b2 install
--  *****************************************************************************************************
CMake Error at /Users/pascaljardin/Desktop/dlib-19.0/dlib/add_python_module:108 (message):
   Boost python library not found.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/pascaljardin/Desktop/dlib-19.0/tools/python/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
error: cmake configuration failed!
```

from starting from scratch. This is how I installed everything on my macbook air os x el captain version 10.11.5

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
$ brew update
$ brew install python3
$ brew install boost --with-python3
$ brew install cmake
```

So is there something I'm don't doing right when I'm installing everything? I really don't know why this is happening and I would really like to install dlib using

```
python3 setup.py install
```

in the lib folder.

Or is there an easier way install dlib with python3?

Comment: what is the boost python library name do you have in your system?

Comment: see also: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/35

Comment: I'm using boost 1.60, which is the compatible to blender 2.77

Answer (score 1):

You neglected to install boost::python.

```
brew install boost-python --with-python3
```

Some time ago, Homebrew spit them into two packages.

Comment: when i install python3 setup.py install

[100%] Linking CXX shared library dlib.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"boost::python::detail::init_module(PyModuleDef&, void ()())", referenced from:
_PyInit_dlib in dlib.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: ** [dlib.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
error: cmake build failed!

Comment: That could be from trying to use 2 different python installs in your project. If you've installed another python (via Homebrew for instance) you need to ensure that your project and boost::python are using the same python.